# Problems to create a Thumbnailimage from a WORD document in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a ThumbnailImage to Word document. I use a UIWebView to load the document and then transform it into an image. Png. I've watched a thousand times and the file path is correct, but the final image is blank. Someone can look at my code to see if there is something wrong?. Thank you very much in advance.

```
UIWebView *myWebView22 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

path44 = [caminoINICIAL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"documentoInicial.doc"];

NSURL *fileURL22 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path44];

NSURLRequest *req22 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL22];

[myWebView22 setScalesPageToFit:YES];

[myWebView22 loadRequest:req22];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myWebView22.bounds.size);

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 0); 

[myWebView22.layer renderInContext:c];

UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

pngPath = [caminoINICIAL stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imagenFinal.png"]];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's a timing problem. UIWebView has is own threads and loads the document async, you need to wait until it's loaded before you use renderInContext.

Figuring out the time might be tricky, either with a fixed time or some deep-subview-inspection.

You might wanna use QuickLook instead of UIWebView to get a little bit more control about the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are firing the request then immediately capturing the image.  `loadRequest:` is asynchronous.  It sends the request, and returns immediately.  It doesn't wait until the document has loaded before returning.  So when you capture the image, the device is still busy loading the document.

You can provide a delegate to the web view that receives a message once the document has finished loading.  Capture the image from within that delegate method.